# In CSS the Bottom Part of my Custom Fonts are Getting Cut Off (the g's and y's)

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why letters that drop below the line (like g and y) in my paragraph are getting cut off.  I tried setting the line height higher but it still cut them off.  I played with font-size in px, pt, and em but still no luck.  Now when I set the font-size much larger (like 3.0em) the problem disappears.  But I need the font to be about this size.

Here is the link: http://sportegy.com/font-test/font-test.html

You'll need to use the link and see the .ttf font I have in order to really see the problem.
However, I'll paste my HTML here too.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: lib-font;
src: url('css/LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
font-family: lib-bold;
src: url('css/LiberationSansNarrow-Bold.ttf');
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>

<span style='font-family: lib-font;color: #232322;font-size: 1.0em;'>   
The quick brown foxy was jumping over the green doggy.<br/>
The quick brown foxy was jumping over the green doggy.<br/>
The quick brown foxy was jumping over the green doggy.<br/>
The quick brown foxy was jumping over the green doggy.<br/>
The quick brown foxy was jumping over the green doggy. 
</span>
```

Comment: Looks like a font issue, not a css issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be cut off for me

Comment: I don't think it is a font issue.  Like I said, if i increase the font-size to 3.0em then the problem goes away.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome 24 and Firefox 18.  Both show the problem for me.  But in my Android JellyBean brown I don't have the problem.

Comment: The link is now a broken link. Would you have a screenshot?

Comment: Can you please mark Daniel Imms's  solution as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only reproduce it at exactly 16px (1em on my browser), so I suspect a font issue like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967004/why-are-my-descenders-being-cut-off-when-using-css-font-face) and [here](http://www.dafont.com/forum/read/8058/tops-bottoms-of-fonts-being-cut-off-how-can-i-correct-this).

You could use the font as-is and avoid 16px, fix the font metrics yourself (as described in the links), email the font creator, or choose a different font.  Lots of good free fonts out there, all the best :)

Answer (score 26):

Try

```
line-height: normal;
```

Seemed to fix a [few people's problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/699659/1156119).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have the same issues as author have. Your answer helps me :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try increasing the line-height to something like `line-height: 1.2;`

If you bump the font size up to 1.1em, it doesn't get cut off.

I suggest using a CSS reset like [Normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the only way I've found to fix this error seems to be changing the font size. 
There seems to be a few errors with certain custom fonts, mainly in Chrome.

I had the same issue and changed the font size from `30px` to `32px` and it's fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the descender value of the font file is too short. Descenders are letters like p,g,q or y. These letters reach under the baseline so the font file should include a value greater than the lowest descender. The browser consider the ascenders and descender values to be the font "container" so it will cut any element going beyond those values. Because of this, CSS cannot fix this problem as the issue resides in the font file itself.

In order to fix it, the only way is to edit the font file and change those values. Try to reach out to the original designer.

Unfortunately, this is bound to happen with free fonts...

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
letter-spacing: normal;
```